# How to restart a page in C# for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I restarted a page, Game.xaml using

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Game.xaml?random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative));
```

However, for now, I have to restart the page depends on the value that I selected a page before. To get the value that I selected a page before, I used

```
int selectedLevel = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationService.GetLastNavigationData());
```

Game.xaml will displayed the data depends on the value that I choosen a page. But if I restart the page now, no data is displayed. Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a global variable in App.xaml.cs?

public string Variable { get; set; }

(App.Current as App).Variable = "Hi i'm global";

Comment: Hi Cheese, I do not understand. For now, I am able to get the value from Main.xaml.cs(A page before) and pass it to Game.xaml.cs. However, if I restart Game.xaml.cs using a button, no data is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstantiate the page by the following

```
            //Refresh homepage
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("pageURI", UriKind.Relative));´
```

pageURI should be changed to the page you want to reinstantiate.